# Calling a multiple argument function generated by 'lambdify' on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, sympy

I wrote an expression f in SymPy as shown in the code and then converted into a function using `lambdify`. Then, I vectorzed it using `np.vectorize(f)`to be able to apply it on a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp
a = Symbol('a')
x = Symbol('x')
b = Symbol('b')
c = Symbol('c')

from sympy import *
f = exp(-(a+b+c)*x)*(4+exp(-(a+b)*x) -2*exp(-a*x) - 2*exp(-c*x))
f = lambdify([x,(a,b,c)], f)
vff = np.vectorize(f)

t = np.arange(0, 5, 0.01, dtype=np.float64)
y = vff(t, (1,1,1)) # (1,1,1) stands for (a,b,c)
```

But while doing so, the last line throws following error.

> `TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 1 required positional argument: '_Dummy_191'`.

I think the syntax might be wrong. I searched on internet, but could not find the right syntax. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [8]: print(f.__doc__)                                                                                             
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, arg_1)

Expression:

(exp(x*(-a - b)) + 4 - 2*exp(-c*x) - 2*exp(-a*x))*exp(x*(-a - b - c))

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, _Dummy_166):
    [a, b, c] = _Dummy_166
    return ((exp(x*(-a - b)) + 4 - 2*exp(-c*x) - 2*exp(-a*x))*exp(x*(-a - b - c)))
```

Imported modules:

`f` can be run with:

```
In [9]: f(np.arange(3),(1,1,1))                                                                                      
Out[9]: array([1.        , 0.13262366, 0.00861856])
```

Since `f` works with an array input, I don't think you need the `vectorized` form.

I get your error if I call `vff` with one argument:

```
In [14]: vff(np.arange(3))                                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 1 required positional argument: '_Dummy_166'
```

With 2 arguments I get a different error:

```
In [15]: vff(np.arange(3),(1,1,1))                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
<lambdifygenerated-1> in _lambdifygenerated(x, _Dummy_166)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x, _Dummy_166):
----> 2     [a, b, c] = _Dummy_166
      3     return ((exp(x*(-a - b)) + 4 - 2*exp(-c*x) - 2*exp(-a*x))*exp(x*(-a - b - c)))

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

That's because `vectorize` is passing scalar `1` as the second argument.  `vectorize` passes scalar tuples to the function, not arrays.  It's designed from functions that take scalar arguments, not arrays or even tuples.  There are some ways around that - but keep in mind that `vectorize` is **not** a speed tool.

Since you don't want `vectorize` to iterate on the (a,b,c) argument, we can 'exclude' it:

```
In [16]: vff = np.vectorize(f, excluded=[1])                                                                         

In [17]: vff(np.arange(3),(1,1,1))                                                                                   
Out[17]: array([1.        , 0.13262366, 0.00861856])
```

That works the same as `f` (above).  But it is much slower:

```
In [18]: timeit vff(np.arange(300),(1,1,1))                                                                          
5.29 ms ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: timeit f(np.arange(300),(1,1,1))                                                                            
103 µs ± 41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`vectorize` is even slower than a list comprehension:

```
In [20]: timeit np.array([f(i,(1,1,1)) for i in range(300)])                                                         
3.91 ms ± 6.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```